# How to change the 'Column' part of the Address Property

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code named `Search` that finds the cell reference of a search item. After that I want to get the range of the searched value using:

`Search.Address`

Once vba gets the address, say `$A$1`, I would like to change `$A` to `$M`, so the return value will be `$M$1`

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rangeAddress As String

    rangeAddress = Range("A1").Address

    Debug.Print "Before conversion: " & rangeAddress

    SwapColumn rangeAddress, "M"

    Debug.Print "After conversion: " & rangeAddress
End Sub

Private Sub SwapColumn(ByRef r As String, ByVal newCol As String)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(r, "$")
    r = vbNullString
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If i = 1 Then
            r = "$" & r & newCol & "$"
        Else
            r = r & arr(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

run the `Main()` sub and check out the Immediate Window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

---

or use it as a spreadsheet function like this

```
=SwapColumns(A1, "M")
```

add the code to a module

*note:* the Sub is called `SwapColumn` and the function `SwapColumns` with a `s` at the  end.

```
Function SwapColumnS(r As Range, newCol As String) As String
    Dim rngAddress As String
    rngAddress = r.Address
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(rngAddress, "$")
    rngAddress = vbNullString
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If i = 1 Then
            rngAddress = "$" & rngAddress & newCol & "$"
        Else
            rngAddress = rngAddress & arr(i)
        End If
    Next i
    SwapColumnS = rngAddress
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering, do you mind explaining how you came up with the solution? Thanks!

Comment: my `rangeAddress` variable holds cell's address as string ex. `$A$1`. You send that variable through reference to another sub in order to modify that same variable. You add an additional parameter to the sub `newCol` which is the new column to be replaced in the `rangeAddress` variable. You add a Variant type array and use Split() function to split the `rangeAddress` variable into parts based on the separator which is the `$` *dollar sign*. Then you iterate over the `arr` array - knowing that arr(1) will store the column number you make a conditional `if` statement. you recreate `rangeAddress`

Comment: by iterating over the `arr` array adding each, earlier separated part back to the `rangeAddress` variable plus adding back the `$` dollar signs when required. Subs do not return values therefore you work with the original `rangeAddress` variable passed to the sub through reference. Almost identical thing applies to the function except you need to return a string variable back to cell that's where the `SwapColumns = rngAddress` comes from - its the return value. Is that all clear now?

Comment: @MichaelBanawa cool, you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you! there's the green checkmark top-left corner of the answer

Comment: @MichaelBanawa it's not only the rep, it's far more complicated. But since your answer has an answer that is satisfactory to you then it should NOT attract other programmers and *waste* their time trying to help you. Everyone who is trying to help is doing it for free and nobody has won the free time on a lottery ;) questions with accepted answers also help keep the system tidy and help any future visitors find answers to their questions faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner?

```
Debug.Print Range("M" & Range(rangeAddress).Row).Address
```

Where `rangeAddress` stores `$A$1` or any other address.

Comment: +1 for the one liner solution I didn't think of!!! I'd give you +10 for that if I could!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I must be missing something, why not simply use REPLACE:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rangeAddress As String

    rangeAddress = Range("A1").Address

    Debug.Print "Before conversion: " & rangeAddress

    rangeAddress = Replace(rangeAddress, "$A$", "$M$")

    Debug.Print "After conversion: " & rangeAddress
End Sub
```